# Hold the transform position of an animation while on hover

Tags: css, animation, hover, css-animations, css-transitions

I want a text to move a few pixels up when on hover. Let's say I want the animation to last 2 seconds but if after those 2 seconds I'm still on hover I don't want the animation to repeat again and again. I just want the position of my text to hold where it is while I'm on hover.

I tried this but not working:

```
.css-class:hover {
  animation-name: in;
  animation-duration: 2s infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.css-class {
  animation-name: out;
  animation-duration:2s;
}

@keyframes in {
  from {transform: translateY(0px);}
  to {transform: translateY(-35px);}
}

@keyframes out {
   from {transform: translateY(-35px);}
   to {transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your class block and `:hover` block add this line of code

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Comment: Thanks, it totally worked. Sorry but my low reputation doesn't allow me to upvote your response. Btw I also had to remove the animation-iteration-count.